# convergence criteria in while loop

Tags: matlab

I have an equation Y = DX. Y is n by k, D is n by m and X is m by k. In each iteration, I use a column of Y and algorithm runs and some columns of D are updated. In iteration 1 algorithm uses column 1 of Y and dictionary is updated, for iteration 2 it uses column 2 of Y and so on.

In each iteration D is updated, I want to use criteria [(norm(D-D1),'fro')^2 < 0.0001]  in which it does not need to run algorithm k times. D means current dictionary which is updated and D1 is the dictionary that updated in the previous iteration.

```
D1=D1+0.05*randn(n,m);   % initializing D1 for first iteration to calculate d
d=D-D1;
delta= norm(d,'fro')^2;
k1=0;

while delta>0.0001
    D1=D;

    for i=1:k
    Y(:,i) = ..
     ...
    algorithm
      ...
    end
    d=D-D1;
    delta= norm(d,'fro')^2;
end
```

I write it in this form, but it is not correct since it iterates k times but I want iterate j < k times that satisfies convergence criteria.

thanks for your attentions

Comment: I corrected my writing I mean that algorithm runs J (unknown) iterations that fewer than k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I believe you want it to exit the loop if convergence is met. So you just return if convergence is met.

```
for i=1:k
    D1=D;
    Y(:,i) = ..
    ...
    algorithm
    ...
    d=D-D1;
    delta= norm(d,'fro')^2;
    if delta>.0001
        return
    end
end
```

Comment: As an alternative, you may use `break` instead of `return` to allow executing some code after the `for` loop.